# Python script to move files

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to organize files in a folder. If the files are in the root folder the script works fine, but when I add a line to run check for files within subfolders it's not working as expected

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, glob, re, os, shutil
from termcolor import colored
#enconding: utf-8

dir_series = "/home/user/series/series/"
dir_temp = "/home/user/stuff/shared/temp/"

buscar = "*[sS][0-9][0-9]*"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_temp):
    for series in files:
        if series.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv')):
            arch_encontrados = len(series)
            print(colored("\nArchivos encontrados:",'red', attrs=['bold'] ), colored(arch_encontrados, 'red', attrs=['bold'] ),'\n')
            print(*series, sep = "\n")

            for serie in series:

                #Extraer el nombre de la serie
                nombre = re.findall(r'.*[\. ][sS]\d', serie)[0]
                nombre_final = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]\d','',nombre).replace('.',' ')
                #Extraer el número de la temporada
                season = re.findall(r'[\. ][sS]\d\d', serie)[0]
                season_final_numero = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]','',season)
                season_final = ('season ' + season_final_numero)
                #Armar el directorio final
                for series_path in os.listdir(dir_series): #lista el contenido de /home/user/series/series/
                 if nombre_final.lower() == series_path.lower(): #compara el listado con la salida del nombre de la serie sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas
                    for season_path in os.listdir(dir_series + series_path):
                     if season_final == season_path: #compara el listado de seasons contra season_final que tiene mayuscula
                        path = os.path.join(dir_series, series_path, season_final)
                        print(path)
                     else:
                        path = os.path.join(dir_series, series_path, 'Season ', season_final_numero)
                 else:
                    print(colored("\n\n*****************************************",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
                    print(colored("** Directorio no encontrado, creándolo **",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
                    print(colored("*****************************************\n",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
                    path = os.path.join(dir_series, nombre_final, season_final)
                    print(path)
                    os.makedirs(path) 

                #Mover el archivo
                print(colored('\nCopiando','green'), serie, colored('a', 'green'), path + '/' + serie)
                shutil.move(serie,path)



        else:
            print(colored('\nNo hay archivos para organizar.','green', attrs=['bold']))

            input(colored("\n\nPresione Enter para continuar ...", attrs=['blink', 'bold']))
```

When I do this in the root it works fine

```
dir_series = "/home/user/series/series/"

buscar = "*[sS][0-9][0-9]*"

series = [s for s in glob.glob(buscar) if s.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv'))]
if series:
    arch_encontrados = len(series)
    print(colored("\nArchivos encontrados:",'red', attrs=['bold'] ), colored(arch_encontrados, 'red', attrs=['bold'] ),'\n')
    print(*series, sep = "\n")
```

Any ideas? thanks

**/edit:
I believe I've fixed that. Now I'm getting another error, when trying to do the last shutil.move it says**

```
print(colored('\nCopiando','green'), serie, colored('a', 'green'), path + '/' + serie)
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

**New code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, glob, re, os, shutil
from termcolor import colored
#enconding: utf-8

dir_series = "/home/user/series/series/"
dir_temp = "/home/user/stuff/shared/temp/"

buscar = "*[sS][0-9][0-9]*"

series = [os.path.join(root, s) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_temp) for s in files if s.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv'))]
if series:
   arch_encontrados = len(series)
   print(colored("\nArchivos encontrados:",'red', attrs=['bold'] ), colored(arch_encontrados, 'red', attrs=['bold'] ),'\n')
   for series_base in series:
      print(os.path.basename(series_base), sep = "\n")

   for serie in series:

    #Extraer el nombre de la serie
    nombre = re.findall(r'.*[\. ][sS]\d', os.path.basename(serie))[0]
    nombre_final = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]\d','',nombre).replace('.',' ')
    #Extraer el número de la temporada
    season = re.findall(r'[\. ][sS]\d\d', serie)[0]
    season_final_numero = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]','',season)
    season_final = ('season ' + season_final_numero)
    #Armar el directorio final
    coincidencia = False
    for series_path in os.listdir(dir_series): #lista el contenido de /home/user/series/series/
     if nombre_final.lower() == series_path.lower(): #compara el listado con la salida del nombre de la serie sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas
        coincidencia = True
        coincidencia_season = False
        for season_path in os.listdir(dir_series + series_path):
         if season_final == season_path: #compara el listado de seasons contra season_final que tiene mayuscula
          coincidencia_season = True
          path = os.path.join(dir_series, series_path, season_final)
          print(path)
         if not coincidencia_season:
          path = os.path.join(dir_series, series_path, 'Season ' + season_final_numero)
          print(path)

    if not coincidencia:
     print(colored("\n\n*****************************************",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
     print(colored("** Directorio no encontrado, creándolo **",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
     print(colored("*****************************************\n",'cyan', attrs=['bold']))  
     path = os.path.join(dir_series, nombre_final, season_final)
     print(path)
     os.makedirs(path) 

    #Mover el archivo
    print(colored('\nCopiando','green'), serie, colored('a', 'green'), path + '/' + serie)
    shutil.move(serie,path)

else:
   print(colored('\nNo hay archivos para organizar.','green', attrs=['bold']))

   input(colored("\n\nPresione Enter para continuar ...", attrs=['blink', 'bold']))
```

Comment: Since every time you set `path` is inside a conditional, it's possible that when you reach the `print(colored('\nCopiando','green'), ...` line that `path` has not been set. Maybe give it a default value somewhere?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, it moved file to the fixed path

Comment: Well, sure, but that means that -- as I pointed out in my earlier comment -- you are never hitting those conditionals correctly. So hopefully that gives you something specific to look at. Maybe break out `print` or `pdb` to verify that variables have the values you think they do when you hit those various conditional statements.